# Laravel model relationship issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Currently i having two model, Roundtable and Table Category, i created a relationship between them with the code below.

Roundtables

[image: roundtables]

table_categories

[image: table_categories]

Table category model

```
public function roundtables(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Roundtable');
}
```

Roundtable Model

```
public function table_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Table_Category');
}
```

My controller

```
public function show(Request $request){
    $id=Auth::user()->id; //Logged user id is 1
    $table= Roundtable::where('user_id',$id)->get();
    return view('users.tables.show')->withTables($table);

}
```

This should connect them right?

Then when i try to show

```
 @foreach($tables as $table)
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="{{ route('table_page',['id'=>$table->id]) }}">{{$table->name}}</a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">View</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $table->table_category->name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

It will occur error "Trying to get property of non-object".

Can i know what is the problems?

Comment: give it a try with `Roundtable::with('table_category')->where('user_id',$id)->first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways. First is by using relationships. At your Controller try something like this:

```
public function show(Request $request){
    $id=Auth::user()->id; //Logged user id is 1
    $table= Roundtable::with('table_category')->where('user_id',$id)->get();
    return view('users.tables.show', compact('table'));
}
```

`users/tables/show.blade.php` should remain the same in this scenario.

The second way:

On your Roundtable Model add the following method:

```
public function getCategoryAttribute(){
        $category = CategoryModel::where('id', $this->attributes['category_id'])->first();
        if(!$category ){
            return "";
        }
        return $category->name;
    }
```

and in your view you have to change from:

```
{{ $table->table_category->name }}
```

to

```
{{ $table->category }}
```

Answer (score 1):

`get()` will return collection. Use `first()` to get an object:

```
$table = Roundtable::where('user_id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: If using $table = Roundtable::where('user_id', $id)->first(); the page showing result will appear "Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: This means that `$table` is `null`. You can check it with `dd($table)`. You're getting `null` when there are no tables where `user_id = $id`

Comment: Yes is null, i posted my database table column. Do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: As I said this means there is no table for that user. For example `Roundtable::where('user_id', 1)->first()->table_category->name;` should show you `Entertainment`, because there is a table for user with `id = 1` and there is a category for this table. You can check if result is `null` with `is_null()`

Comment: Yes my logged user id is 1, that why i dont know the reason why it still return null.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `first`:

```
$table->table_category()->first()->name
```

Comment: Having Error "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name"

Comment: Answer updated. Given that a ```Roundtable``` can only belong to 1 ```TableCategory```, you can call ```first``` on the relationship.

Comment: Still having "Trying to get property of non-object", i updated my controller code, is they related?

Answer (score 0):

You are using get() in the query. It is an eloquent collection.

You need to use foreach or first for the query.

like,

```
foreach($table as $item){
   $item->table_category->name
}
```

or

```
$table= Roundtable::where('user_id',$id)->first();
$table->table_category->name
```

I hope, it will help you.